# thread.run() works and thread.start() not works

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

Following is my main class.

```
public class ShareData {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShareReader aShareReader = new ShareReader("http://test.com:9000", "dilip.id@gmail.com", "password");
        Thread fileThread = new Thread(aShareReader);
        fileThread.run(); // fileThread.start() not calling the run() method
    }
}
```

If I type fileThread.run() run method is called.  If I call fileThread.start() the run metod is not called.  Following is my thread class.  I dont know what I am doing wrong.

```
public class ShareReader implements Runnable {

    private String itsShareURL =    null;
    private String itsUserId        =   null;
    private String itsPassword      =   null;
    private String itsAuthToken     =   null;
    private String itsLoginURL      =   null;
    private String itsChannelUpateURL   =   null;


    /**
     * 
     */
    public ShareReader(String theShareURL, String theUserId, String thePassword) {
        this.itsShareURL    =   theShareURL;
        this.itsUserId          =   theUserId;
        this.itsPassword        =   thePassword;
        this.itsLoginURL        =   itsShareURL + "/v1.0-SNAPSHOT/login";
        this.itsChannelUpateURL =   itsShareURL + "/v1.0-SNAPSHOT/updateChannelSubscription/";
    }

    public void run() {
        JSONObject json;
        JSONArray jsonArray;
itsAuthToken = getToken(itsUserId, itsPassword);
    updateChannelList(itsAuthToken);

    String aURL = "http://test.com:9000/v1.0-SNAPSHOT/userTimeline/"+itsAuthToken+"/";
    try {
        String lat = null;
        String lon = null;
        String udid = null;
        String dateTime =  null;
        String eventID = null;
        aEventBean = new EventBean();
        jsonArray = readJsonArrayFromUrl(aURL);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            lat = json.getString("lat");
            lon = json.getString("lon");
            udid = json.getString("udid");
            eventID = json.getString("eventId");
            dateTime = json.getString("dateTime");
            aEventBean.setItsLatitude(lat);
            aEventBean.setItsLongitude(lon);
            aEventBean.setItsUDID(udid);
            aEventBean.setItsEventIdentifier(eventID);
            aEventBean.setItsDateTime(dateTime);
            System.out.println(udid + " ---> " +lat + " ==== " + lon);
            sendData(aEventBean);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
}
```

Sorry If I ask so basic question..
Ideally I need to do fileThread.start() to start a thread..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: How do u know that the thread is running. Can u paste the entire run() method.

Comment: I put a break point inside the run() metod and it is not hitting it.  even the print statement inside the run() method is not printing..

Comment: This seems very strange. Calling start() will in turn call run() once the thread executes.

Comment: could you please post your full run method?

Comment: Yes I can do that..  I will paste in few min..  Thank you verymuch for all your help..

Comment: Yes @JimmyGustafsson it is strange..  I dont know why it happens..

Comment: I have added the whole run method @DhruvGairola

Comment: Did you try calling `fileThread.join()` after `.start()`? (It is possible that your prgram ends before the threads gets a chance to be scheduled, calling `.join()` will prevent that.)

Comment: There is something odd about the code you've posted. Why is the constructor for class `ShareReader` called `InterShareReader`? Can you show us your *actual* code?

Comment: Sorry @aix I just replaced InterShare as Share in my code which I have posted.

Comment: Thanks @rsp I will try and let you know..

Comment: Where did you add your print method?

Comment: WOW @rsp it worked.. Please paste it as solution I will mark it as correct..  Thank you very much..

Comment: Thanks @DhruvGairola the problem is as rsp told.. Program exits before the run method called.. Thank you for answering..

Comment: @rsp what are the reasons a program might end before the thread might get scheduled?

Comment: @Dhruv Gairola, the reason why it works with the `.join()` call is that it forces the main thread to wait for the thread it just started. "Falling off the end" of the `main()` method Java will end the program, which is prevented by waiting for the other thread.

Comment: @rsp right, but why would it fall off the end of the main method? its pretty interesting. i know what join does but im intrigued by this behaviour.

Comment: @Dhruv Gairola, the call to `.start()` is the last line in his `main()` method. The next thing Java will do is end the program unless there are no non-daemon theads still running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`run()` is definitely called if you call `start()` on `fileThread`. Check your implementation of `run()`- its very likely that this method completes or terminates before your check for the print statements. Just an fyi, `fileThread.run()` is a sequential call while `fileThread.start()` is a parallel call.

Another vague possibility is that you're not implementing Java's runnable; instead, that may be some custom Runnable class in your project.

**EDIT:**

So apparently calling `fileThread.join()` helped you fix your problem, but why does this work? If you call `fileThread.join()`, the main thread waits until the target (in this case, your `fileThread` object) terminates.

Comment: @Dilip Rajkumar, let Dhruv have the tick :-) I'm glad it worked.

Comment: Possibly just because it didn't get the time needed to get started. (unless somewhere in the code it is set to be a daemon thread, in which case it won't prevent prgram end.)

Comment: Thank you verymuch.. @rsp  It worked great..  Finally I am going to integrate with one swing application..  I just need to know why it does not work...  Thanks once again..

Answer (score 0):

fileThread.run() never starts a new thread. To start a new thread you have to call fileThread.start().